# Django_norel error 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'operators' appengine

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I'm using django_norel and followed all the install directions but I get this error:

```
 Exception Value:   
     'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'operators'
```

when I go to the following view (return a JSON object of nicknames):

```
def listUsers(request, thread_id):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
    else:       
        thread_user_list = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=UsersThreads.objects.filter(thread=thread_id).values('pk'))
        data = serializers.serialize( 'json', thread_user_list, ensure_ascii=False, fields=('nickname'))
        return HttpResponse(data)
```

All I'm trying to do is send a JSON object of a thread's users.

It's definitely related to the filter because I tried simply returning HttpResponse("asdf") and that worked. So I'm guessing it's a problem with Joining and norel databases. This code has worked when I was running on the sqlite database (maybe the filter function changed a bit while debugging).

Here are my models:

```
 class UserProfile(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=25)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
     facebook_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     def __unicode__(self):
     return self.nickname

 class Thread(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tagline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    founder = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

 class UsersThreads(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.thread.name
```

I created UsersThreads because I was trying to avoid the google-app-engine not letting you do joins. I'm a confused about the need for django_norel.

Here's the python error code:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/users/4/

Django Version: 1.3
Python Version: 2.5.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'djangotoolbox',
 'dbindexer',
 'djangoappengine']
Installed Middleware:
('dbindexer.middleware.DBIndexerMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/asdf/threadchat_main/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/asdf/threadchat_main/threadchat/views.py" in listUsers
  162.         data = serializers.serialize( 'json', thread_user_list, ensure_ascii=False, fields=('nickname'))
File "/Users/asdf/threadchat_main/django/core/serializers/__init__.py" in serialize
  91.     s.serialize(queryset, **options)
File "/Users/asdf/threadchat_main/django/core/serializers/base.py" in serialize
  39.         for obj in queryset:
File "/Users/asdf/threadchat_main/django/db/models/query.py" in _result_iter
  107.                 self._fill_cache()
File "/Users/asdf/threadchat_main/django/db/models/query.py" in _fill_cache
  774.                     self._result_cache.append(self._iter.next())
File "/Users/asdf/threadchat_main/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  275.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/Users/asdf/threadchat_main/djangotoolbox/db/basecompiler.py" in results_iter
  219.         for entity in self.build_query(fields).fetch(low_mark, high_mark):
File "/Users/asdf/threadchat_main/djangotoolbox/db/basecompiler.py" in build_query
  278.         query.add_filters(self.query.where)
File "/Users/asdf/threadchat_main/djangotoolbox/db/basecompiler.py" in add_filters
  73.                 self.add_filters(child)
File "/Users/asdf/threadchat_main/djangotoolbox/db/basecompiler.py" in add_filters
  76.             column, lookup_type, db_type, value = self._decode_child(child)
File "/Users/asdf/threadchat_main/djangotoolbox/db/basecompiler.py" in _decode_child
  87.         packed, value = constraint.process(lookup_type, value, self.connection)
File "/Users/asdf/threadchat_main/django/db/models/sql/where.py" in process
  329.                     connection=connection, prepared=True)
File "/Users/asdf/threadchat_main/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py" in inner
  53.             return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/asdf/threadchat_main/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in get_db_prep_lookup
  156.                 sql, params = value._as_sql(connection=connection)
File "/Users/asdf/threadchat_main/django/db/models/query.py" in _as_sql
  941.             return obj.query.get_compiler(connection=connection).as_nested_sql()
File "/Users/asdf/threadchat_main/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_nested_sql
  136.         return obj.get_compiler(connection=self.connection).as_sql()
File "/Users/asdf/threadchat_main/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  68.         where, w_params = self.query.where.as_sql(qn=qn, connection=self.connection)
File "/Users/asdf/threadchat_main/django/db/models/sql/where.py" in as_sql
  92.                     sql, params = child.as_sql(qn=qn, connection=connection)
File "/Users/asdf/threadchat_main/django/db/models/sql/where.py" in as_sql
  95.                     sql, params = self.make_atom(child, qn, connection)
File "/Users/asdf/threadchat_main/django/db/models/sql/where.py" in make_atom
  171.         if lookup_type in connection.operators:
File "/Users/asdf/threadchat_main/dbindexer/base.py" in __getattr__
  9.         return getattr(self._target, name)
File "/Users/asdf/threadchat_main/django/utils/_threading_local.py" in __getattribute__
  183.             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /users/4/
Exception Value: 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'operators'
```

Comment: Any ideas for tests I can run? I'm tempted to just reinstall everything...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is your install. I am getting the same problem when I try to do a django-nonrel "join". Maybe you can start by simplifying the code of thread_user_list by first getting the primary keys and confirming that your request is correct.

Comment: Were you able to figure out the "join" problem? I was able to retrieve by primary key correctly, but anytime I filter by filters, I still get the error.

Comment: Actually I no longer use django-nonrel on GAE. The couple of django features that I was using don't require to have django managing your data. I currently use the GAE db model and feed it to django template.